# MessageSource.getMessage always returns default message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For some reason messageSource always returns default error messages. Here is my configuration.

```
/**
 * ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource allows reloading of resource bundle contents without
 * a server restart.
 *
 * @return MessageSource
 */
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames(new String[]{
            "/WEB-INF/messages/com/company/global/service/login/login_locale"
    });
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the messages using `MessageSource.getMessage(fieldError, locale)` . The response I get is listed below.

```
{
    "fieldErrorViews":[
        {
            "fieldName":"oldPassword",
            "message":"may not be empty"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my message property files into `src/main/resources/com/company/global/service/login` directory and change the base name to `claspath:com/company/global/service/login/login_locale`. This fixed the issue.